# Access an ArrayList from a method in another class

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6

I am trying to make a program that takes input from a file and then searches for the input in a different file, for example, it takes the word "car" from file A and outputs the location of the word(if the word is included) in file B.

At the moment I have 3 classes. A main class, a class to read the file input and a class to search for the input in another file.

The class that reads the input has code that takes the files, reads the file line by line and saves each word into a variable, and then adds these variables into an arrayList.

This is part of the code:

```
List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
     while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
          String [] tokens = strLine.split("\\s+");
          String [] words = tokens;
          for(String word : words){
              listOfWords.add(word);
              System.out.print(word);
              System.out.print(" ");      
          } 
        System.out.print("\n");  
    }
        in.close();
        return listOfWords;    
    }
```

I then need to take the arrayList and put it into the class with the code that searches for the words in an external file.

This is part of the code that searches for the words:

```
public void search(List<String> listOfWords) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(getSearchFileName());

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            for(String list: listOfWords){
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(list);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);

        int start = 0;
        while (m.find(start)) {
            System.out.printf("Word found: %s at index %d to %d.%n", m.group(), m.start(), m.end());
            start = m.end();
                }
            }
          }  
}
```

The code works standalone, but I am having trouble calling the arrayList (listOfWords) from the first set of code and using it in the second set of code, which are in different classes.

Any help with what code I need to add or adjust will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a matter of scope. If you're going to use that list across a class or between methods you can consider:

1. *Returning* the list on the first method, saving it in a field or variable and passing it to the second method.
2. *Make the list a class field* and manage it. That way you'll be able to access it in the second block of code, assuming both blocks are on the same class.

As it is, the list is defined within the scope of the first block of code (the `while` loop), which I presume is an extract of an actual method. Once the method is finished, the list is eligible for GC (in other words, as good as discarded).

Comment: I have managed to get the code to access each other in a single class, but it requires me to call my one method **public void search(List<String> listOfWords) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{** the problem is that I don't know how to call it in my main method, which is in a different class. Any idea on that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking your question... since public methods can be accessed and invoked on a class instance, as long as you instantiate your class like `MyClass myClass = new MyClass();` you can invoke `search` by doing `myClass.search(listOfWords);`.

Comment: Ya, I know how to instance my class. I just couldn't access the arrayList because it was inside the while loop. Thankfully another comment has cleared that up for  me. Unfortunately I need to get mysearch method to get called inside my main method. Normally i would call my 3rd class and search method by doing this `MyClass3 myclass = new MyClass3();` and then `myclass.search();` , but because my search method is now `public void search(List<String> listOfWords)` , `myclass.search();` doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not getting the full picture here. `myclass.search()` doesn't have any parameters? Is it another interemediary class that invokes `search(List<String listOfWords)`?. I don't understand why would you have a search method with no parameters at all, unless the parameters were defined inside of it. In that case you can change that search method to receive the search parameters.

Comment: Ok, my main method is in my 1st class, and I need to invoke my search method `public void search(List<String> listOfWords)` (which is in my other class), in my main method.

Answer (score 1):

Your method  return type should list. Then you can call that method by object reference or static variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having can be understood by learning variable scope, move and define your listOfWords out of the while loop.

```
List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            String [] tokens = strLine.split("\\s+");
            String [] words = tokens;
            for(String word : words){
                listOfWords.add(word);
                System.out.print(word);
                System.out.print(" ");      
            } 
            System.out.print("\n");  
        }
in.close();
return listOfWords;
```

Comment: Thanks, this does improve my program a lot. Just trying to access the array list in another class now.

Answer (score 1):

`listOfWords` is a local method variable, its scope is restricted to the while loop. Therefore it can't be accessed by another method. There're two ways to deal with it:

1. The first method can return `listOfWords` and is called in `search()`.
2. If both methods are in the same class, `listOfWords` can be a class field, which all the methods in the class can accessed.

Answer (score 1):

i will answer your question from your topic :
you need to define your array list in the class body (out of the function body) and set it as a public and ( if you wanna access with out initiate your class just set it as static) :

```
class A 
{

 public static List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
void func()
   {  
//......
while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        String [] tokens = strLine.split("\\s+");
        String [] words = tokens;

        for(String word : words){
            listOfWords.add(word);
            System.out.print(word);
            System.out.print(" ");      
        } 
        System.out.print("\n");  
    }
    in.close();
```

}
}

here how to access from your class B:

```
 class B
{
   funcInClassB ()
 {
   myArrayList=A.listOfWords();
  }
 }
```